# Inserting toc entry, but wrong page number shows

Tags: table-of-contents

I inserted two pages in landscape mode as `,pdf` files (which are tables that take up the entire page), and I want to include them in the TOC, listed as a section.

Since the table takes up the space of an entire page, I did not want to use a `\section{myTable}` command, which would put the section name on a page all by itself. I tried:

```
... my p. 97 content

\pagebreak % Location A

\addtocounter{section}{1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thesection . \,\, my Table name}

% Location B

\begin{landscape}

\begin{figure}[t]
\scalebox{1}[0.85]{\includegraphics[width=1.7\textwidth, clip=true,trim= 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm]{myTable_p1.pdf}}
\label{fig:myTablep1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=1.7\textwidth, clip=true,trim= 0cm 4cm 0cm 4cm]{myTablep2.pdf}
\label{fig:myTablep2}
\end{figure}

\end{landscape}

\newpage

\section{myNextSection}\label{nextsect}
```

`Table_p1` appears properly on page 98. `Table_p2` appears properly on page 99.  And `myNextSection` appears properly on page 100. But in the TOC, section `myTable` is listed on page 100, not on page 98. If I move the `\pagebreak` command from location A to location B, then in the TOC, section `myTable` is listed on page 97, not on page 98.

I also tried using `\clearpage` or `\newpage` instead of `\pagebreak`.

I also tried:

```
... my p. 97 content

\pagebreak % Location A

\addtocounter{page}{-2}

\addtocounter{section}{1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thesection . \,\, my Table name}

% Location B

\addtocounter{page}{2}
```

and many other variations in placement of the two `\addtocounter{page}` commands, all to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You don't really want to show your email address to every spammer around.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to do the job, but I am supposing you are not using `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\lipsum


% Location B
\clearpage
\addtocounter{section}{1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\contentsline{section}{\string\numberline{\thesection}my Table name}{\the\value{page}}}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{figure}[t]
\scalebox{1}[0.85]{\includegraphics[width=1.7\textwidth, clip=true,trim= 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm]{example-image-a}}
\label{fig:myTablep1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=1.7\textwidth, clip=true,trim= 0cm 4cm 0cm 4cm]{example-image-b}
\label{fig:myTablep2}
\end{figure}

\end{landscape}

\newpage

\section{myNextSection}\label{nextsect}

Some text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks jfbu.  Two tweaks were needed. Instead of `\numberline{\thesection}my Table name`, I needed `\numberline{\thesection.}\hspace{-0.5em}my Table name`.
I am not currently using `hyperref` but probably want to in the future. Also, I am using `pdflscape` package instead of `lscape` package.